# Как правильно преобразовать в PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

Нашел в интернете вот такую [инструкцию](http://php-include.ru/stati/postranichnaya-navigaciya-php) по выводу постраничной навигации.

Захотел переделать с помощью PDO, чет не выходит) ошибок никаких не выдает, поэтому незнаю в чем может быть проблема, кнопки Назад и Далее появляются, но данные не выводятся.

```
$sum = 10;
$post = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS a FROM post');
$post->execute();
$arr = $post->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
  $str = (int) $_GET['p'];
}
else{
  $str = 0;
}
$start = $str * $sum;
$postt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT "'.$start.'", "'.$sum.'"');
$num_rows = $postt->fetchColumn();
if ($str > 0)
{
  $p = $str - 1;
  echo '<a href=index.php?p=' . $p . '>НАЗАД</a>';
}
$str++;
if($start + $num_rows < $arr) {
  echo '<a href=index.php?p=' . $str . '>ДАЛЕЕ</a>'; 
}
while ($bases = $postt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo $bases->h1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то, единственное что нужно для такого перевода - это хотя бы немного изучить PDO. В частности, твердо выучить, что

1. Любые переменные, в любой запрос, всегда, при любых обстоятельствах должны попадать только через плейсхолдеры. А PDO - это единственное API, которое позволяет сделать это удобоваримо.
2. PDO позволяет получить нужные данные сразу, без предварительной записи в массив.
3. PDO умеет сообщать о любых проблемах - главное его правильно настроить.

Поэтому рекомендую не просто скопипастить готовый код, а сначала прочесть [**статью**](http://www.phpfaq.ru/pdo), в которой все это описывается. Тем более что наличие рабочего кода еще не гарантирует отсутствие ошибок.

```
// сколько выводим на страницу
$per_page = 10;

//получаем номер текущей страницы 
$cur_page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) 
{
    $cur_page = $_GET['page'];
}

// получаем сдвиг для лимита 
$start = ($cur_page - 1) * $per_page;

// получаем общее количество записей
$count = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS a FROM post')->fetchColumn();

Получаем данные для вывода
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?,?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $per_page,   PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($cur_page > 0)
{
  echo '<a href=index.php?p=' . $p . '>НАЗАД</a>';
}

if($start + $per_page < $count) {
  echo '<a href=index.php?p=' . $str . '>ДАЛЕЕ</a>'; 
}
foreach ($data as $row){
  echo $row['h1'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но тут с переменными что-то не так, не работают кнопка < | >